# WebStart Application is not working in Java 7 u45

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

My Eclipse RCP application ( launched with WebStart (.jnlp)) crashes on startup while launching with Java 7 u45 (working fine in java6).

I've added to the manifest:
Permissions: all-permissions
Codebase: *
Trusted-Library: true

This removed error dialog popup. But I still have a startup issue. I see following messages (Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase) in java console while  downloading many jarfs/plugins

```
security: JAVAWS AppPolicy Permission requested for: http://vspdlpd05.atldev.com/PDTeller-v73allyusdev2ix/app/plugins/j2ee_1.6.0.jar
ruleset: finding Deployment Rule Set for
        title: Profile Direct Teller Wrappering Feature
        location: http:vspdlpd05.atldev.com/PDTeller-v73allyusdev2ix/app/features/com.fnis.ally.teller.wrapper_2.0.0.jnlp
        jar location: vspdlpd05.atldev.com/PDTeller-v73allyusdev2ix/app/plugins/j2ee_1.6.0.jar
        jar version: null
        isArtifact: true
ruleset: no rule applies, returning Default Rule
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.51
network: Created version ID: 1.5+
network: Created version ID: 0+
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://vspdlpd05.atldev.com/PDTeller-v73allyusdev2ix/app/plugins/j2ee_1.6.0.jar
```

Whereas the same changes (modified all the manifest files with above attributes) done in to a different repository seems to be working fine with java 7 u45.

Any help would be appreciated.